# How to generate Okta access token programmatically?

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, okta-api

In my Okta tenant, I have created a SPA and that authentication part is working fine. My API is a separate one and it's spring boot microservice.  I already integrated it with spring boot Okta starter. It's also working fine (Both Authentication and Authorization). But for my service's tests (integration tests), I need to generate access token to use as Authentication token, programmatically which I still stuck on. I was able to generate session token using following API,

https://dev-xxxx.okta.com/api/v1/authn

{
  "username": "client@xx.com",
  "password": "xxxxxx",
  "options": {
    "multiOptionalFactorEnroll": false,
    "warnBeforePasswordExpired": false
  }
}

Can someone help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you use a different OAuth app configured in Okta to use the Resource Owner Password flow. You pass it a username and password, just like the authentication API you posted above.

You also need a client id and a client secret, which is why you'd need an additional app defined in Okta - a SPA app doesn't get a client secret.